# extending loadablecomponent with base page object

Tags: java, generics, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the selenium page object pattern and trying to incorporate the loadable component into this. I want to have a Parent Page Object class that all the page objects extend from which will have my common methods.

I am struggling to get this to work without getting a java out of memory error. When I debug I get the following error

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

At the end of the test there is no stack trace just a out of memory error.

So my parent page object class is as follows ( after searching this was the only way it didnt throw a compile time error)

```
public abstract class SeleniumPageObject<T extends SeleniumPageObject<T>> extends LoadableComponent<T> {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    protected void clearAndType(WebElement field, String text) {
        field.clear();
        field.sendKeys(text);
    }

    protected String getPageTitle() {
        return driver.getTitle();
    }

}
```

I then have a page object (simplified below)

```
package selenium.selenium_test;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;


public class HomePage extends SeleniumPageObject {

    private final static String baseUrl = "https://someUrl";
    //WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = "a[href*='tell-me-more']")
    WebElement link_TellMeMore;

    @FindBy(css = "a[href*='registration']")
    WebElement link_Register;


    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super();
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        Assert.assertTrue("Home page has not been loaded correctly", baseUrl.equals(url));
    }   

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        driver.get(baseUrl);        
    }

    public RegisterPageOne clickRegisterLink() {
        link_Register.click();
        return new RegisterPageOne(driver);
    }
}
```

My test class is very simple it has this line of code in my method

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
```

When I hit the pagefactory it hangs and then throws the error. I can only think that i have used the generics incorrectly.

Any one help with what I have done wrong? Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I also changed the class signature to below but still got the same error

```
public class HomePage extends SeleniumPageObject<HomePage>
```

I also did a little more debugging into the code and it is the following line in PageFactory method that throws the runtime exception. When it tries to create a new instance of my homepage class. The page class to proxy parameter is passed in as class selenium.selenium_test.HomePage and it does find the constructor for this class.

```
private static <T> T instantiatePage(WebDriver driver, Class<T> pageClassToProxy)
Constructor<T> constructor = pageClassToProxy.getConstructor(WebDriver.class);
return constructor.newInstance(driver);
```

below is the stack trace I get when running the test from Maven. When running direct from Eclipse only the top five lines are output.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:561)
    at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:210)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.Failure.getTrace(Failure.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4StackTraceWriter.writeTrimmedTraceToString(JUnit4StackTraceWriter.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.encode(ForkingRunListener.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.toString(ForkingRunListener.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.testError(ForkingRunListener.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.testFailure(JUnit4RunListener.java:110)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFailure(SynchronizedRunListener.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$4.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:142)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFailures(RunNotifier.java:138)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFailure(RunNotifier.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.addFailure(EachTestNotifier.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

Comment: Post your full code - at a minimum, we need to see PageFactory.initElements()

Comment: updated the home page code and added my test class code

Comment: I still can't see the PageFactory code...

Comment: the page Factory code is from the selenium framework. import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

Comment: OK, there's no-where in PageFactory that should be iteratively creating objects, can you also post the full stack trace?

Comment: i have updated the post with my stack trace.

Comment: Assuming that's the full stacktrace, it's not clear that PageFactory.initElements() is the culprit (it's not in the trace). The only exception that should be possible, is if HomePage cannot be instantiated, but I can't see the problem there. I can see that one of your JUnit test cases is failing, but can't see more, and you've found a workaround anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue changing the PageFactory Line to below solves the issue

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```